# Build the docker image with environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

so the objective is to have a different image for prod and testing so there are certain variables change accordingly so I need to set env variables during the build.

```
# Dockerfile
ENV Somename: $value
...
```

`docker build --build-arg Somename=value -t test .`

`docker run -d -p port:port test`

this work flow is not taking the env variables

Comment: You should have multiple Dockerfiles. A Dockerfile should not be dependant on any variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to consume the build-arg inside you dockerfile using the `ARG` command.

```
FROM alpine

# consume the build arg    
ARG somename  

# persist the env variable in the built image
ENV somename=$somename  

# somename will appear as an env variable
RUN echo $somename 
RUN env
```

And running the build command `docker build --build-arg somename=hello .` will show you an env variable `somename=hello`

Answer (score 2):

your syntax is not correct, do not put

`:`

it is either

`ENV somename somevalue`

or

`ENV somename=somevalue`

Check the doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env